# ObjectDisposedException on scrollview renderer

Tags: xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, event-handling

I am firing the following event in my Xamarin application:

```
AppEvents.Instance.UI.RiseSearchStringTypingEvent(this, new EventArgs());
```

The **HomePage.xaml.cs** codebehind subscriber-event performs an auto scroll to top every time the event is being fired (on every input on the search field)

```
void OnSearchStringTyping(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    scrollView.ScrollToAsync(0.0, 0.0, true);
}
```

when the searchstring is complete and the user hits the submit-button, the **Oncompleted()** method invokes on the **SearchHeaderView.xaml.cs** which navigates to the **SearchPage**

```
void OnCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tag = this + ".OnCompleted";
    try
    {
        if (string.Compare(LastSearchText, SearchEntry.Text) == 0) return

        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
        {
            SearchRequest();
        }
        else if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
        {
            var task = new Task(SearchRequest);
            task.Start();
        }

        LastSearchText = SearchEntry.Text;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Track.Exception(tag, ex);
    }
}
```

This procedure works perfect on iOS platforms...But in android, when i submit my search string, the app crashes with an **ObjectDisposedException** on the **ScrollView**

I think the problem is that the application tries to scroll up the view again **after** it navigates away from the homepage. The **SearchRequest()** method on Android is not invoked in a new Thread, but iOS is. How can i fix this? I can not just make the method being invoked asynchronously, because the Search doesn't work then.

Comment: can you add your renderer's here that will make things a little easy for us

Comment: i don't have a custom renderer for the scrollView

Comment: well your question says otherwise `ObjectDisposedException on scrollview renderer
`

Comment: yes, but this Exception is related to the scrollView renderer from Android, not to a custom renderer inherited from that because i don't have one

Comment: Okay, I see no problem, can you tell me what version of XF do you have?

Comment: My XF version is 3.4.0

Comment: I remembered seeing a bugzilla report with regards to this in XF lemme just browse and find it

Comment: Can you add the Error output and stacktrace if possible?

Comment: there is no stacktrace it says `Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ScrollViewRenderer'.`

Comment: There is nothing further in regards to what happened because i am kinda sure there will be?

Comment: no, just the text and a message in the properties section with same content

Comment: you posted an answer a few hours ago, have you deleted it?

Comment: Umm i am pretty sure its still there even though i have negative marking for no reason anyway it is there

Comment: aah now it has appeared again

Comment: Please check these and respond to me if anything works for you or not